# HttpOnly cookie setting in local deployment but not remote deployment

Tags: javascript, httponly, chalice

I have a local server that successfully sets an `HtmlOnly` cookie on a local client, but the same code on a remote server is not setting the cookie.

The local server is a Chalice server running on `http://localhost:8000`. The response headers are:

```
{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:5000', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 
    'Set-Cookie': 'refresh-token=my_token_value; <Max-Age>=605000; Path=/; HttpOnly'
}
```

The local client is running on `http://localhost:5000'`. It is calling via `fetch`:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/login", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors'
})
```

The remote server is running on something like `https://my-server-domain.com/api`. The response headers are:

```
{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://my-client-domain.com', 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true', 
    'Set-Cookie': 'refresh-token=my_token_value; <Max-Age>=605000; Path=/; HttpOnly'
}
```

The remote client is running on something like `https://my-client-domain.com`. It is calling the same way as the local client:

```
fetch("https://my-server-domain.com/api/login", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors'
})
```

The API calls to the remote server *work* -- they return the expected response -- but the cookie is not getting set to the browser. Any suggestions as to why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big difference between my local deployment and remote deployment was running over `https`. What ended up working was setting `SameSite=None; Secure` to the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try to simple set the cookies directly on client, then send to server

Comment: When I set a cookie manually with `document.cookie = 'simple_key=simple_value; path=/'` the cookie appears in my local server but not on my remote server. I've also tried adding combinations of  `'; secure'`, `'; domain=my-server-domain.com'` and `'; domain=https://my-server-domain.com'`. No cookies appear on my remote server.

Comment: Seems like that it's a server-side configuration, try to handle the basics for functionalities checking.